# Sql join 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have struggle to produce good SQL.
It is a relationship part of application.
I have 3 tables : users('id'), relationship('user_id', 'member_id'), relationship_block('user_id', 'blocked_member_id')

I would like to get all members belonging to user with user_id that are not blocked.

Records of first table 'users' that are in 'relationships' table but that are NOT in 'relationship_blocked' table.
First 2 i can do with JOIN, but then I want to remove those that are blocked.

Thanx.

edit: found a good info about it here: http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
    from users u
        inner join relationship r
            on u.user_id = r.user_id
        left join relationship_block rb
            on r.user_id = rb.user_id
                and r.member_id = rb.blocked_member_id
    where rb.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/* this would get the user */
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = $ID

/* build on this to get relationships */
SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN relationship r ON r.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = $ID

/* build on this to get not blocked */
SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN relationship r ON r.user_id = u.id
JOIN relationship_block b ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = $ID
  AND r.member_ID <> b.blocked_member_id

/* get all users that NO ONE has blocked */
/* this means if there exists a record b such that b.blocked_member_id
   equals the user X has blocked user Y, do not include user Y.
   By extension, if X and Y are fierce enemies and have blocked eachother,
   neither would get returned by the query */
SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN relationship r ON r.id = u.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT null
                   FROM relationship_block rb
                   WHERE rb.blocked_member_id = u.id
                 )
/* This runs two queries at once. The inner query says "I'm not getting any
   columns, because I don't care about the actual data, I just to get all
   records where someone has blocked the user I'm currently looking for".
   Then you select all users where that isn't true. For good speed, this would
   require an index on relationship_block.blocked_member_id */
```

Comment: As a side note, don't `SELECT *` ... that's for illustrative purposes only!

Comment: It occurs to me that this can be interpreted to mean you need three queries to get this done. You don't. The first two were merely showing the thought progression of how I would build the query required.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to work. It may be that in relationship_blocks table is only one or 2 rows (blocks) but there is many more user rows.

Comment: In even more easier explanation I need to return all members from relationship table (all member_ids) that are not present in relationship_blocks table . Therefore for example if there is no row in relationship_blocks table it would return all the users. If there is 1 row in relationship_blocks table that has : 'user_id' = 1 , 'blocked_member_id' = 4 then it would return all users (presented in relationship table as member_id) except for user with id 4

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This would now work. Although for nature of my application I can't mix 2 selects to one, so I'll go with solution bellow. Thank you. For anyone else outthere looking for same thing, I found good info here: [link](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Comment: You know, we have a giant app that they told us the same thing to. They had a 24 second query they wanted faster, and when I said we should use a `not exists` they said "it's already too slow, we can't do a second query in it!" Well, we did the `not exists` anyway, and it took it down to 2 seconds (from 24... and much of that, I believe, is transactional overhead.) So, I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss the notion that you can't afford to do a second query.